# Updating PHP on CentOS 6 - "Error: Package: php-pecl-ncurses"

Tags: php, centos6, update

On a CentOS 6 I am trying to update my PHP from 5.3 to 7.x by following the instructinos at https://www.mysterydata.com/how-to-install-upgrade-to-php-7-4-on-rhel-centos-vestacp/.

When I do the final step:
`yum install php php-opcache php-gd php-curl php-mysqlnd`

I get error:

```
Error: Package: php-pecl-ncurses-1.0.1-1.el6.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: php(api) = 20090626
           Removing: php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (@base)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Updated By: php-common-7.2.34-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
               php(api) = 20170718-64
           Available: php-common-7.2.33-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
               php(api) = 20170718-64
Error: Package: php-pecl-ncurses-1.0.1-1.el6.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Removing: php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (@base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Updated By: php-common-7.2.34-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
               php(zend-abi) = 20170718-64
           Available: php-common-7.2.33-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
               php(zend-abi) = 20170718-64
```

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Please note that CentOS 6 is EOL since Nov 2020 and won't receive any update.
Please consider upgrading to a supported version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `php-pecl-ncurses` requires the php api for the 5.3 version, so you may remove it from your system, before your install:

```
yum remove php-pecl-ncurses
```

You may also want to check if there are any other PECL packages installed and see if they should also be removed:

```
rpm -qa '*pecl*'
```

Then run the command install/update your PHP installation:

```
yum install php php-opcache php-gd php-curl php-mysqlnd
```

Comment: Uninstall did the trick, thanks!